# fixing missing hours and dates in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of dates for 1985 (hourly): for each day there is 24 hours. My object is `fg`, here's an example:

```
fg

 "1985-01-01 00:30:00 GMT" to "1985-01-01 22:30:00 GMT" then NA # (NA here should be "1985-01-01 23:30:00 GMT")

 "1985-01-02 00:30:00 GMT" to "1985-01-02 22:30:00 GMT" then NA # (NA here should be "1985-01-02 23:30:00 GMT ")

 "1985-01-03 00:30:00 GMT" to "1985-01-03 22:30:00 GMT" then NA

 "1985-01-04 00:30:00 GMT" to "1985-01-04 22:30:00 GMT" then NA

 str(fg)
 POSIXct[1:8760], format: "1985-01-01 00:30:00" "1985-01-01 01:30:00" 

 class(fg)
 [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

the last hour `23:30:00` is missing in each day so I want here to replace `NA` with last hour of that day.

Comment: "24 times" means what? Like 24 hours?

Comment: Is your `fg` a sequence from 1985-01-01 00:30:00  in hourly increments with all of the 23:30s missing?  How did you generate the sequence?  Can you just regenerate the whole thing with `seq(from=as.POSIXct('1985-01-01 00:30:00',tz="GMT"), to = as.POSIXct('1985-12-31 23:30:00',tz="GMT"),by=60*60)`

Answer (score 1):

You should really give us a reproducible example ([How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)).  But the following seems to work on my example of your data

```
library(lubridate)
fg <- c(ymd("2015-12-01"), ymd("2015-12-02"), NA)
as.POSIXct(ifelse(is.na(fg), c(as.POSIXct(NA), fg[-length(fg)]) + hours(1), fg), origin="1970-01-01")
```

Note: I am using `lubridate` to create the example, but also for the `hours` function.

Note 2: not sure where the need for the outside as.POSIXct comes from, but it is needed.